# How to check reference counting issues when doing direct manipulations of CPython objects?

Tags: debugging, cython, cpython, reference-counting

I'm doing some experiments with direct manipulation of pointers to `PyObject` (and its derivated types) from Cython. Is there a tool or debugging technique that I could use to check I didn't mess up with the reference counting mechanism? Especially, I would like to know when a program terminates if I forget to `Py_DECREF` some objects, causing potential memory leaks.